# Dynamic video layout creation in react js for video conference website

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently developing a video conferencing website. Since I am new to react js, I don't know what I should do for creating video layouts automatically when a person joins a room.

Here is the code snippet:-

```
class Chat extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { loading: true, message: "hello", mutedAudio: false, mutedVideo: false, fullScreen: false };
    this.peerConnections = [];
    this.peerConnection = null;
    this.roomId = props.roomId;
    this.remoteVideoRef = React.createRef();
    this.localVideoRef = React.createRef();
  }

openUserMedia = async () => {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
    this.setState({ localStream: stream });
    this.localVideoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
    this.remoteVideoRef.current.srcObject = new MediaStream();
    this.joinRoom(this.roomId);
  };

render() {
    return (
      <div className="ChatMain">
        <div className={this.state.loading ? "Chatloader" : "hidden"}></div>
        <div className={this.state.loading ? "" : "hidden"}>Connecting...</div>
        <div className={this.state.loading ? "hidden" : ""} id="videos">
          <div className="ChatMessage">
            <span>{this.state.message}</span>
          </div>
          <video id="remoteVideo" ref={this.remoteVideoRef} className="active" autoPlay playsInline></video>
          <video id="miniVideo" ref={this.localVideoRef} className="active" muted autoPlay playsInline></video>
        </div>
        
        <Icons className={this.state.loading ? "" : "hidden"} 
        mutedVideo={this.state.mutedVideo}
        mutedAudio={this.state.mutedAudio}
        onMutedAudio={this.onMutedAudio}
        onMutedVideo={this.onMutedVideo}
        onHangUp={this.hangUp}
        
        ></Icons>
      </div>
    );
  }

       componentDidMount() {
       this.openUserMedia();
  }
}
```

I want a code like, everytime a person joins a meeting a video of the person joining the meeting should be visible to the creator of the room and this process should happen dynamically, I.e, whenever a new person joins a new layout should be created adjacent to the previous one.

Comment: What do you mean by `creating video layouts`? What exactly you want to change?

Comment: The code should be like, everytime a person joins a meeting a video of the person joining the meeting should be visible to the creator of the room and this process should happen dynamically, I.e, whenever a new person joins a new layout should be created adjacent to the previous one

Comment: I believe that you should hold an array of members in state. When someone is joining the array will be updated using `setState` which will trigger re-render for the component so the layout will changed.

Comment: I want a example code snippet based on your idea.

Comment: You do? :) I'm sorry but I don't have the time for this. I offered a direction. Based on the keywords I used (`setState`, `array` etc.) you can do a research about how to update component based on array in state. If you have a question after you implemented it, let me know..